# Бот для мода Diablo II

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект, c++

Поддавшись ностальгическому порыву решил поиграться в один из фанатских модов для **Diablo II**, и через пару часов был измучен однообразностью происходящего. И тут в голове появилась идея: а почему бы не написать бота, который будет вместо меня проходить игру, которая надоедает всего за два часа. Как это в принципе можно сделать?

---

*Расплывчатые ответы на  вопросы от DreamChild*

Прежде всего, я делаю это **just for fun**, для тренировки своих навыков программиста, и это своего рода проба пера в написании искусственных интеллектов, поэтому не надо меня отговаривать.

**Во-первых**, всё в **Diablo** -- спрайты, которые упакованы в mpq, и народными умельцами создан не один распаковщик, так что эти спрайты можно извлечь и научить ИИ их распознавать уже будет проще (знаем, что искать). С текстовой информацией ещё проще: нам надо распознавать конкретный шрифт (ну хорошо, два шрифта) конкретного размера. Впрочем, распознавать противников даже не обязательно: если при наведении мыши на какую-то область появляется надпись вверху экрана, то это противник, которого надо атаковать. В итоге бот должен различать только шрифты и всё, что летит в его сторону (ИИ, дмаю, лучше сделать заточенным на дальний бой).

**Во-вторых**, для каждого персонажа есть свой "билд" -- определённый шаблон прокачки. Для простоты можно взять одного персонажа и создать для него такой шаблон, по которому ИИ будет раскидывать очки характеристик и умений.

**В-третьих**, человек подбирает более качественный шмот только потому, что ему лень без конца бегать к торговцам. ИИ может действовать по алгоритму набил инвентарь, сравнил со своим, пошёл в город, продал, купил новый свиток портала, вернулся на локацию.

**В-четвёртых**, задания в таких играх примитивные, их не так много, поэтому условия их получения и выполнения можно все вручную прописать. Что касается карты: большинство игроков только тем и занимается, что полностью прочёсывает локации в поисках опыта и более качественного шмота.

**В-пятых**, выяснить какой лук лучше не так уж сложно: тот, у которого урон больше (сравнивать по окну статов персонажа). А по остальным эффектам есть подсказка: чем сильнее предмет, тем он дороже. Единственная загвоздка с различными сопротивлениями, но тут можно заставить ИИ считать, от чего он больше урона получает и в соответствии с этим стремиться повысить то, или иное сопротивление. Но лучше написать ИИ, который вообще не получает повреждений, или сводит их к минимуму.

**В-шестых**, какие преимущества даёт **SDK**? В **Torchlight** и **Titan Quest** он имеется, но какие это даёт преимущества?

Comment: А мене бы бота что бы писал сайты на php сам)))

Comment: Думаю, серьёзные дяди уже заняты решением подобной проблемы, а бот для дьяблы, думаю, всё-таки намного проще написать.

Comment: Напишите бота :) Что за система у вас, Windows? Если не семерка, то попробуйте посылать клиентскому окну программы сообщения от клавиатуры и мыши (эмулировать пользовательский ввод). Только вот с распознание происходящего на экране будут большие проблемы. Короче интересную тему вы затронули, но большую и очень сложную.

Comment: Как раз Windows 7. Думаю, должны быть какие-то более изощрённые подходы, чем делать влоб распознавание текста и образов. Хотя в дьябле всё двумерное и спрайтовое, так что это должно быть немного проще, чем распознавание простой картинки. Должен быть другой способ...

Comment: @Montreal, по-сути, DreamChild прав, вам по-сути нужно искусственный интеллект написать, который смог бы справиться с подобной задачей.

Comment: @SoloMio, в общем-то так и есть. Бот в общем случае — слабый или узкоспециализированный искусственный интеллект. Современные шахматные программы — тоже боты, только играют уже лучше человека. Я просто подумал, что для **Diablo** и тому подобных, который худо-бедно справляется со своей задачей будет *относительно* несложно написать.

Comment: @Montreal уязвимое место этих ответов в их излишней расплывчатости. С тем же успехом можно на вопрос "Как работает трансформатор?" ответить "Ж-ж-ж-ж". Дьявол, как известно, кроется в деталях, а деталей этих - легион. Скажем, одна только маленькая фраза "бот должен различать только шрифты" подразумевает уйму рутинной работы. А при желании таких деталей (очень и очень трудновыполнимых с технической точки зрения) на каждый ваш ответ можно найти еще миллион. 
Впрочем, дорогу осилит идущий.

Comment: А вот что касается SDK, то я не подразумевал что-то конкретное (и уж тем более речь шла не от Titan Quest или Torchlight), а имел в  виду некое гипотетическое API, позволяющее осуществлять взаимодействие с ядром игры на более "цивилизованном" уровне, нежели беспорядочный отлов пикселей на экране. Возможно, SDK перечисленных вами игр способны как-то решить эту проблему, но чтобы с уверенностью об этом говорить, нужно разбираться с этими SDK

Comment: @DreamChild у нас конкретный шрифт конкретного размера конкретных цветов и даже, зачастую на конкретных фонах. Это сильно упрощает задачу...

Хотя, наверное, я действительно напишу какую-нибудь игру наподобие змейки и буду учить ИИ в неё играть. Так, наверное, будет проще удовлетворить своё любопытство.

Comment: @Montreal, если что-нибудь да напишите, поделитесь результатами. А то я тоже не первый год уже о собственном "Джарвисе" мечтаю.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На 146% уверен, что игра не стоит свеч в плане трудозатрат по сравнению с окончательным результатом.  Судя по всему в природе не существует некоего Diablo-SDK, который помог бы в решении задачи (для широкой аудитории я имею в виду), а писать логику подобного бота  вручную - занятие утомительное, муторное и ненадёжное. Теоретически, конечно, можно попробовать научить этого бота распознавать образы на экране и эмулировать мышиные клики и нажатия клавиш. Однако тут видится море проблем.

Во-первых, в этой игре громадное количество всяческих противников. Десятки видов, если не сотни. Очевидно, всех их потребуется каким-то образом распознавать. Можно, конечно, попробовать убивать всё, что шевелится, но это чертовски неэффективно хотя бы потому, что многие из них имеют различные заклинания, от которых боту не помешало бы уметь защищаться, а также ряд из них имеет защиту или даже иммунитет к тем или иным магическим воздействиям, что тоже немаловажно.

Во-вторых, нужно каким-то образом научить его "прокачиваться". Для бота, да еще и такого, что захватывает изображения, это весьма нетривиальная задача.  Впрочем, вопрос выбора тех или иных навыков при достижении  нового уровня можно оставить на откуп человеку

В-третьих, нужно как-то научить его как-то подбирать выпавшее из противников снаряжение и предметы, причем не какие попало (а их там навалом), а только наиболее ценные.

В-четвёртых, бот должен уметь  выполнять задания (пусть их там и немного) и находить себе путь на карте. Карты, как известно, в Diablo II генерируются автоматически

В-пятых, бот должен уметь использовать лучшее оружие, снаряжение и заклинания из того, что есть в его распоряжении.  Правильное комбинирование всего этого барахла типа доспехов, сапогов, шлемов, амулетов, колец, оружия, собственных характеристик персонажа, его умений таким образом, чтобы характеристики одной вещи не аннулировались свойствами другого предмета - задача и для человека не всегда очевидная.

По-моему, вопросов пока больше, чем ответов. Поэтому, если есть желание попрактиковаться в написании ботов, то я бы на вашем месте выбрал какую-нибудь другую игру, которая предоставляет чуть больше возможностей для подобных манипуляций

Comment: для начала что-нибудь простенькое, какую-нибудь браузерку, ну или вообще что-то онлайновое, что обменивается пакетами с сервером, думаю, с подобными играми будет несколько проще

Comment: Ну да, проще в плане обмена информацией. В принципе, если знать особенности клиент-верверной архитектуры какой-нибудь ММО, то можно для неё написать бота, который в неё гриндит.

Но у меня появились ответы на вышеуказанные вопросы.

Comment: @DreamChild, по поводу окончательного результата (ожидаемый уровень эндорфинов у автора), позвольте с Вами не согласиться.

@Montreal, а Вы молодец. Вас запугивают, а Вы не поддаетесь.

Comment: @avp полагаю, это зависит от индивидуальных предпочтений. Скажем, мне подобная деятельность не кажется интересной, а следовательно, и эндорфин таким занятием у меня,думаю, не поднимешь)) Однако, вполне допускаю, что для ТС эта задача более привлекательна

Comment: @avp спасибо за похвалу) Я уже привык к тому, что 90% моих идей встречает сопротивление окружающих. Наверное, это одна из причин их низкой реализации. К тому же, я понимаю сложность поставленной задачи. Сложно испугать человека тем, что он уже и сам знает.

Comment: Ну и писать игру, а потом искусственный интеллект, который будет в неё играть мне кажется верхом шизофрении. Хотя...

Comment: @Montreal, когда-то, в начале своих занятий программированием, я пристал к своему старшему коллеге, а как бы написать какую-нибудь свою интересную игрушку. Скажем, шашки или преферанс.

Он замечательно ответил. Знаешь, говорит, программирование игр это самое дурацкое занятие. В любом случае ты убедишься, что сам дурак. 

Если игрушка обыграет тебя -- дурак, т.к. проиграл какой-то железяке, а если наоборот, то тоже дурак -- хорошую программу написать не способен.

Comment: @avp сейчас существуют шахматные программы, которые человек обыграть не в состоянии и, если мне не изменяет память, даже чемпионаты по шахматам проводятся среди таких программ. Так что не только дураки "каким-то железякам" проигрывают. Да и суть второго исхода я как-то не уловил.

Comment: @Montreal, о DeepBlue (с сопроцессорами) и Fritz (а также GNU Chess) я безусловно слышал (а с простенькой glchess иногда играю сам (чаще проигрываю)).

--

Вам же скажу, как известно, *в каждой шутке есть доля шутки*.

По поводу второго исхода -- дело в том, что коллега, сказавший это, был весьма неглупым КФМН. (дело ведь в том, что проиграл *своей* программе).